# How do I determine how many active members there were on a date in the past?

Tags: civimember, search, reports

I've been asked to mine CiviCRM to determine how many active members we had on a particular date in the past, i.e. How many active members did we have on Dec 31, 2015?   Is there a search or report that will show me this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this via Find Members since to be an Active Member on that date you need

- a start date before that date AND
- an end date after that date

Comment: After a bit of trial and error, best way to achieve Peter's solution is to use Search Builder.

Comment: did you try our extension? https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.historicmembershipdata

Comment: I did not! Thanks Peter.

Comment: Just used this extension because I did not have logging enabled and it allowed me to asnwer some questions. Petednz is the civi savior.